# problem while installing python package in spyder

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, spyder, librosa

I'm trying to install python library called "librosa" in spyder anaconda.
I tried **conda install -c conda-forge librosa** from [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/librosa) to install package.
This was result [in anaconda shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWCMA.png).

But when I try to import librosa in spyder, it gives [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QORCp.png).
How to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: As far as I can tell your entire installation was performed correctly. The exception seems to originate from the `numba` package. If I were you I'd post this problem at the [numba issues page](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just installed numba package again from [link](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numba) and now **import librosa** works fine.